# How to pare down a set to form a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I already have $5$ vectors, how could I pare down them to form a basis for $\mathbb R^3$?
The vectors $x_1=(1,2,2)^T$, $x_2=(2,5,4)^T$, $x_3=(1,3,2)^T$, $x_4=(2,7,4)^T$, $x_5=(1,1,0)^T$ span $\mathbb R^3$. How to pare down the set $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5\}$ to form a basis for $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pare it down to a basis if you're sure that the vectors span $\mathbb{R^3}$ but from the second part of your question, I understand that you know this.

Work from left to right: you keep the first (non-zero) vector and then proceed as follows:

- if the next vector is a linear combination of the previous ones, leave it out;
- otherwise: keep it and proceed to the next vector.

By eliminating a vector which is a linear combination of the other ones, you don't change the spanned space. By doing this for all the vectors, you will end up with a linearly independent set.

---

Alternatively and perhaps easier to do, you can place the vectors as columns in a matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{2} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{2} & \color{blue}{1} \\
\color{blue}{2} & \color{blue}{5} & \color{red}{3} & \color{red}{7} & \color{blue}{1} \\
\color{blue}{2} & \color{blue}{4} & \color{red}{2} & \color{red}{4} & \color{blue}{0}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Now perform row reduction on this matrix to get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{1} & 0 & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-4} & 0 \\
0 & \color{blue}{1} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{3} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} & \color{blue}{1}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Now the columns with leading $1$'s correspond to linearly independent vectors (marked in blue). You can also deduce the following dependencies: $C_3=-C_1+C_2$ and $C_4=-4C_1+3C_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the matrix $[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5]$ and search the minor with non zero determinant.

Answer (score 0):

Write the vectors a s a column vectors of a matrix and carry out elementary row operation and bring it to echelon form.

Only the columns of the original matrix corresponding to  those contain leading $1$'s in the echelon form will be linearly independent.